# How to open Hyper-V Manager in Hyper-V Server 2012?

Tags: hyper-v, replication

In Windows Server 2012, to open Hyper-V Manager, in Server Manager I would just go Tools >> Hyper-V Manager.

How do I open Hyper-V Manager in Hyper-V Server 2012? I want to allow replication to this server but there is no GUI in Hyper-V Server 2012 and I don't know how to get into the Hyper-V settings without it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need either a Windows 8 workstation or a Windows Server 2012/R2 OS elsewhere, because Hyper-V server does not have the ability to run GUI tools (Hyper-V manager included). You add "Hyper-V" feature on that OS and connect to your Hyper-V server via Hyper-V manager console.

Comment: I was just doing some research based on @Frank Thornton 's response. Will "Remote Server Administration Tools for Windows 8" do the trick?

Comment: @Jslick Yes, RSAT for Windows 8 contains Hyper-V management console.

Answer (score 1):

Hyper-V Server was meant to be controlled from a remote source.

To enable Hyper‑V Manager on Windows

1. In Control Panel, tap or click Programs, and then tap or click
   Programs and Features.
2. Tap or click Turn Windows Features on or off.
3. Select Hyper‑V, tap or click OK, and then tap or click Close.
4. Shut down your PC, and then restart it.
5. Open the Hyper Manager and connect to your server.

Comment: I don't have a GUI.

Comment: Hyper-V Server was meant to be controlled from a remote source.